# Python how to handle test case names split over several lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I used to have new test cases from a database based on tests having this format:

```
TEST_F(CLASSNAME, TESTCASENAME)
```

Now there is a test case with such a long name that the automatic formatting looks like this:

```
TEST_F(

CLASSNAME,

TESTCASENAME)
```

Before I get each piece of information based on the format TEST_F(CLASSNAME, TESTCASENAME) as follows:

```
    print("Looking for new tests")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cpp_tests_dir_path):
        for file in files:
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if "TEST_F(" in line:
                        data = line.split("TEST_F(")[1]
                        c_class = data.split(",")[0]
                        c_test_case = data.split(",")[1].split(")")[0].strip().split()[0]
```

But if there is a test case with such a long name and format as I previously mentioned.  Which already separated into multiple lines

```
TEST_F(

CLASSNAME,

TESTCASENAME)
```

How can I adjust the logic to get the value of each value?

Comment: I think U should drop [tag:bash] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you need to use regular expressions. I don't know what your test cases look like, but if they are made of letters and numbers without spaces you can use this pattern to find the test cases.

`'TEST_F\(\s*\w*\s*,\s*\w*\s*\)'`

You can rewrite your code like this :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cpp_tests_dir_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
            content = f.read()
            test_cases = re.findall(r'TEST_F\(\s*\w*\s*,\s*\w*\s*\)',content)
            print(test_cases)
```

Now if your file's content is like this :

```
TEST_F(CLASSNAME1, TESTCASENAME1)
TEST_F(CLASSNAME2, TESTCASENAME2)
TEST_F(
    CLASSNAME3,
     TESTCASENAME
    )
```

You'll get this as output :

```
['TEST_F(CLASSNAME1, TESTCASENAME1)', 'TEST_F(CLASSNAME2, TESTCASENAME2)', 'TEST_F(\n    CLASSNAME3,\n     TESTCASENAME\n    )']
```

At this step you have all of your test cases in a list, It's up to you to get classname and testcasename from it.

Assuming that classname and testcasename are made of letters and underscore, you can update your code like this :

```
print("Looking for new tests")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cpp_tests_dir_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
            content = f.read()
            test_cases = re.findall(r'TEST_F\(\s*\w*\s*,\s*\w*\s*\)', content)
            for test_case in test_cases:
                cleaned = re.sub(r'[\s]','',test_case) # removing white spaces
                _, c_class, data = re.findall('\w+',cleaned)
                print(_ , c_class, data) # checking results
```

As truly mentioned in comments, It can also be done using groups in regular expressions. The code for it is written bellow:

```
print("Looking for new tests")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(cpp_tests_dir_path):
    for file in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as f:
            content = f.read()
            for c_class, data in re.findall(r'TEST_F\(\s*(\w*)\s*,\s*(\w*)\s*\)', content):
                print(c_class, data) # checking results
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, then I still don't know after I get the output, how to retrieve the exact value of ClassName and TestCaseName.  ? for example this one 'TEST_F(\n    CLASSNAME3,\n     TESTCASENAME\n    )'  I guess I still have to the previous logic

Comment: something like this?                                                                                                content = f.read()
            test_cases = re.findall(r'TEST_F\(\s*\w*\s*,\s*\w*\s*\)',content)
            print(test_cases)
            for line in f:
                    if "TEST_F(" in line:
                        data = line.split("TEST_F(")[1]
                        c_class = data.split(",")[0]
                        c_test_case = data.split(",")[1].split(")")[0].strip().split()[0]

Comment: I don't know what your classname and testcasename looks like, but the idea is pretty much straightforward. You need to remove `TEST_F` and parentheses from the resulted strings. Then strip strings and then split them by comma. Finally you can strip the resulted strings after splitting as well.

Comment: Thanks again for the help on this. I just updated my question and added a regular simple and an issue one.   And also added the update code based on your suggestion.  May I ask if you can lend me a hand to review if I am understand right? Tons of thanks

Comment: I'll update the answer. You need to study more about regular expressions.

Comment: If you want the answer helpful, don't remember to mark it as answer.

Comment: thanks a lot and i will learn about it and sure I will test it out and mark it as helpful. Thanks for your time

Comment: May I ask a dummy question , what this code do? _, c_class, data = re.findall('\w+',cleaned) ?

Comment: Unpacks a list of 3 values to 3 variables

Comment: Using 3 regexes to do what the first regex can already efficiently do is entirely unnecessary. The second regex that removes white spaces is especially redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose the patterns for the names of the class and the test class in parentheses as capture groups so that `re.findall` can output them in a tuple for the `for` loop to unpack into variables:

```
for c_class, c_test_case in re.findall(r'TEST_F\(\s*(\w*)\s*,\s*(\w*)\s*\)', content):
    print(c_class, c_test_case)
```

Comment: Great idea and it reduces a lots of lines